# TFS Continuous integration /Deployment version number

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

We have an WPF application and we versioned it at as follows:

```
Major Minor Build Revision
   1    0     1      35
```

So the complete version is: `1.0.1.35`.

We want to use TFS continuous integration/deployment and we want to preserve the consecutive number, i mean, the next version has to be `1.0.1.36` and so on.

But in the compilation steps we used a task to change all assembly version numbers:

[image]

The $(Buil.BuilID) value currently is 1459, so the new version number will be `1.0.1.1459`.

How can we continue our next version number (`1.0.1.36`) and do it automatically?

Comment: Why does this matter to you? The only important thing is that the revision number increases, not what the revision number actually is. Using a build ID is very common for this.

Comment: It is important for the business itself, because the users are using application with that versioning, so we want to preserve it and dont make a big jump between them

Comment: Again, why does it matter? This is a revision. If you're doing semver, you wouldn't be releasing two builds with the same major.minor.patch, anyway.

Comment: I agree with Daniel here Alex.  Build number jump are very common even in windows between versions.  The important thing is that they increment.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Version number counter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-versioncounter) to use a variable and increment him in each build.

If you use Azure DevOps Server 2019 you can use this syntax (in a variable value):

```
$[ counter(variables['revision', 35]) ]
```

Then the variable will increment in each build.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try it!